# How to convert a date into a list in python

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am writing a program that needs live dates(Means like current date). Here is the code.

```
from datetime import date
today_date = date.today()
print(list(today_date))
```

Now I want to convert this date into a list. But it gives me an error because the element obtained using `date.today()` isn't "iterable". So how do I actually convert the date into a list?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: like turning 2020-06-25 into  2020 ,06 , 25

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you could use `.timetuple` for your purposes:

```
>>> datetime.date.today().timetuple()[:3]
(2020, 6, 25)
```

Comment: And you can wrap it in a `list` if a tuple isn't desired

Answer (score 3):

Each part of the date and time are available as attributes of the datetime object. You can try something like below.

```
import datetime

today_date = datetime.datetime.today()

date_list = [today_date.year, today_date.month, today_date.day]
```

You can also access time similarly

Comment: Is this the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is the answer

Comment: @snoopstick I think you should also check [juanpa.arrivillaga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62582119/9608759) which is more pythonic and easily extendable.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method called `timetuple`:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> today_date = date.today()
>>> today_date.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=177, tm_isdst=-1)
```

As you can see, because you used `date` rather than `datetime`, the time part is zero.

You can convert the first three items to a list:

```
>>> list(today_date.timetuple()[:3])
[2020, 6, 25]
```

If you use `datetime`, then it is used in the same way, but the time part is also populated:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.today().timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=19, tm_min=39, tm_sec=47, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=177, tm_isdst=-1)
```

So you could do, for example:

```
>>> list(datetime.today().timetuple()[:6])
[2020, 6, 25, 19, 40, 35]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the year, month and day as elements in the array.

```
list = [today_date.year, today_date.month, today_date.day]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date
today_date = date.today()
print(str(today_date).split('-'))
```

OR

```
from datetime import datetime
print(str(datetime.now()).split()[0].split('-'))
```

OR

```
datetime.date.today().timetuple()[:3]
(2020, 6, 25)
```

OR

```
import datetime
today_date = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [today_date.year, today_date.month, today_date.day]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `list()`, you can use `split()`:

```
from datetime import date
today_date = date.today()
print(str(today_date).split('-'))
```

Output:

```
['2020', '06', '25']
```

---

---

---

Another thing you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(str(datetime.now()).split()[0].split('-'))
```

Output:

```
['2020', '06', '25']
```